# How power plane acts as a path for the return currents

Tags: emc, signal-integrity, emi-filtering, high-speed

In some pcb stackup's I can see that the power plane is given as reference to signal layers.

I have some questions regarding this.

1. May I know in that case how the return current flows.
2. Assume all my signals present in the layer belongs to 1.8V and I am proving a 3.3V power plane as reference. Will it cause any SI issues.

Comment: Decoupling capacitors act as short circuits for high frequencies

Comment: Do you understand how current flows through a capacitor?

Comment: Does it make any difference at which DC potential the reference plane is, when the AC currents are returning on the plane under the signal traces?